# Dart can you overload the assignment operator?

Tags: operator-overloading, dart

I have the following class:

```dart
class EventableNumber{

  num _val;

  num get val => _val;

  void set val(num v){

    num oldValue = _val;
    _val = v;
    _controller.add(new NumberChangedEvent(oldValue, v));

  }

  StreamController<NumberChangedEvent> _controller = new StreamController<NumberChangedEvent>();
  Stream<NumberChangedEvent> _stream;
  Stream<NumberChangedEvent> get onChange => (_stream != null) ? _stream : _stream = _controller.stream.asBroadcastStream();

  EventableNumber([num this._val = 0]);

}
```

Is it possible to overload the `=` assignment operator? rather than using the `val` getter and setter to enforce the event to fire when the value changes it would be nice if it could just be done when the user writes `myEventableNum = 34` and then `myEventableNum` first its `onChange` event, rather than `myEventableNum.val = 34`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dart doesn't allow this.

However, have you considered a function style call?

Basically, if you define a function called 'call' in EventableNumber class, then you can call the instance as a function:

```
myEventableNum(34)
```

If you decided to go this way, it is recommended to implement the Function interface:

```
class EventableNumber implements Function {
...
  void call(val) {...}
...
}
```

Hope this helps :)